# Cannot access a closed stream? C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a stream which contains signature image from my xamarin forms signature pad. I need to upload the image to server but I getting error:

> FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot
>   access a closed Stream

I am getting the exception in PostAsync line.

How can I access the stream?

```
public async void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signimgurl = await signature.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png);

    image.HeightRequest = 250;

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => 
    {
        return signimgurl;
    });

    var _content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    _content.Add(new StreamContent(signimgurl),
        "\"file\"",
        $"\"{"testsign"}\"");

    var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var _uploadServiceBaseAdress = "http://myserver.rocket.com/api/Files/Upload";

    var httpResponesMessage = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_uploadServiceBaseAdress, _content);
    string _imgLocation = await httpResponesMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Why is `signimgurl` a field, instead of a local variable? Are you calling this method from multiple threads at once? Btw prefixing local variables with `_` is quite the opposite of the coding conventions I've seen so far (but if it's your company's convention, then I guess it's not so big of an issue).

Comment: Please add the stacktrace. Of what type is signimgurl?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GetImageStreamAsync. Does it return a byte array? Other issues I'm finding resolved it by creating a new memorystream in FromStream... FromStream(()=> new MemoryStream(signimgurlBytes) where signimgurlBytes is signimgurl or signimgurl converted, depending on its type and if it's already bytes or not.

Comment: signimgurl is a stream

Comment: Just a suspicion: Could it be that `ImageSource.FromStream` closes the stream when it's done? Could you explicitly check that?

Comment: as @Fildor says, the fact that you are using `signimgurl` two times looks like an error source as your error message is about re-using a closed stream.

Comment: Reusing such a stream in a highly async environment is anyway not the best of ideas, I think.

Comment: @Fildor yes. You are right. ImageSource.FromStream is the one closing the stream. Now can upload perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could point you to the solution. Maybe write your fix as an answer to your own question and accept it. Might be useful for other people with the same issue.

Comment: Please take look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164503/httpclient-multipart-form-data-post-image-and-json-same-time/48562888#48562888